# Problem with multi-line JTextField

Tags: java, uitextfield, jtextfield

I have a `JTextField` and need to have 3 lines in it, such as these:

```
HI
MY name
is mehdi
```

How can I set the text in a `JTextField`? I tried `\n`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1 : JTextField does not support multiline. what you want is a JTextArea

2 : Newlines aren't the same on all systems, you might have to use `"\r\n"` if you are running Windows. Since Java 7, there is `System.LineSeparator` to solve this issue.

(see the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--))

Comment: When you say it doesn't support it, you must be saying that fairly loosely. I am trying to figure out how to stop it supporting multiple lines right now. And yes... the thing I'm dealing with is a JTextField.

Comment: that's odd, i was actually being very literal because according to  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html
"JTextField is a lightweight component that allows the editing of a single line of text"

Comment: (note that this has not changed in Java 8 either)
Are you sure you're not just seeing the text wrap instead of displaying actual multi line text?

Comment: I think I'm actually hitting [a bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6427290). You can get multiple lines in it if you paste and I have been looking for a good solution to it since it occurs application-wide. I wonder if it has been fixed in Java 8 actually.

Comment: I apologize for resurrecting an old post, but I just wanted to tack this comment on because this took me a long time to understand. If I have a JTextArea field in a JPanel and I'm using .getText() then I need to literally hit the enter or tab button to make a newline or tab, I can't type "\n" or "\t".

Comment: That is correct, because if you type `\n`, you get the escaped characters, which are represented as a backslash and the letter n.
If you were to set the content from code-behind, or read it as a string, you would find that the newlines look like `\r\n` on windows, and like `\n` on most other operating systems. ( `area.Text = "This is the first line \r\nThis is the second"` ) (the backslash indicates that we're not looking for the regular letters `r` and `n`)

Comment: I see that the article i linked is no longer present, so i'm updating the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't get multi-line behavior on single-line JTextField,

use JTextArea instead

info:

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080405030738AAJcKjU
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html

Answer (score 1):

```
JTextArea taText = new JTextArea();
taText.setText("\tHI\nMY name\nis Raku");
```