# Append a new line in java Swing jTextfield

Tags: java, swing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with multi-line JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662029/problem-with-multi-line-jtextfield)

How do I append a new line in a Java Swing `JTextField`?

I'm writing a one chat application, in this chat application my input area is a `JTextField` and while the user releases the <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> keys I have to create a new line in the `JTextField`; this is my requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JTextField` does not support multiple lines. Use [`JTextArea`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) instead.