# Java - Saving each line of text instead of replacing it

Tags: java, chat

everytime I write something in the text box and press enter, I'm able to see the message in the "Uneditabletest", however, if I write something different and press enter, It will replace my last message, what do I do to have them saved one after another? Like if it was a chat or something similar.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Tutorial extends JFrame {

JTextField jtfText1, jtfUneditableText;
String disp = "";
TextHandler handler = null;

public Tutorial() {
    super("TextField Test Demo");
    Container container = getContentPane();
    container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    jtfText1 = new JTextField(10);
    jtfUneditableText = new JTextField("Uneditable text field", 20);
    jtfUneditableText.setEditable(false);
    container.add(jtfText1);
    container.add(jtfUneditableText);
    handler = new TextHandler();
    jtfText1.addActionListener(handler);
    jtfUneditableText.addActionListener(handler);
    setSize(325, 100);
    setVisible(true);
}

private class TextHandler implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == jtfText1) {
            disp = "text1 : " + e.getActionCommand();
        } else if (e.getSource() == jtfUneditableText) {
            disp = "text3 : " + e.getActionCommand();
        }

        jtfUneditableText.setText(disp);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Tutorial test = new Tutorial();
        test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to use a list to store your inputs (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858572/how-to-make-a-new-list-in-java)? If you would rather have your program store up to a certain amount of text (ie. up to 10 previous strings) you can use an array to store your strings instead of a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply append it to the end. In this case, it would be `jtfUneditableText.setText(jtfUneditableText.getText() + "\n" + disp)`

Comment: Could you Edit my code? I'm kinda of just learning so I'm not sure how to add getText ):

Comment: If I edit it others won't be able to tell what the question was :)

Comment: I just got it working, however the /n is not giving me a new line, is there anyway to fix that?

Comment: @BobXplosion if you typed `/n` it will never work. Check you typed `\n` and probably use a `JTextArea` instead of a `JTextField`.

Comment: Use JTextField instead of JTextArea.

Answer (score 0):

There should be something like getText() in jtfUneditableText, so you can do `jtfUneditableText.setText(jtfUneditableText.getText() + "\n" + disp);`

So the text in jtfUneditableText will be what was there before (jtfUneditableText.getText()) plus a line break (\n), and the new text.

Comment: Could you Edit my code? I'm kinda of just learning so I'm not sure how to add getText ):

Comment: you don't add getText(). It is a method of the JTextField Class. So just replacing the last line of the actionPerformed method with the line I wrote should work :). Hope that helps! I also added some more info to my answer, so maybe you understand better.

Comment: However, the "/n" is not making a new line as expected Is there anything I can do?

to have them listed

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662029/problem-with-multi-line-jtextfield you should use JTextArea instead of JTextField, since it doesn't support multiple lines. And please check that I used \n not /n