# appending data on newline in string

Tags: java

I am making a BE project "Data extraction using Natural Language processing". Here, the user needs to enter the query in English, which gets converted in SQL and fetches the data from database to the user.

I am using jframes in Netbeans 8.0.1.

Here, I take user input in `Input.java` and store it in varaible `inp`. On the basis of type of query I call the method `Ans()`/`Place()` and append the data in StringBuilder `res`. Finally, I use `setText()` method to display result in `Output.java`, in the textfield `RES`.

I want to modify the display of data in `res`, like making it little bold, append new content on new line, before it gets displayed in RES.

```
private void RunActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Output n1 = new Output();
    inp = this.TF_1.getText();
    System.out.println("inp :" + inp);
    String[] arr = inp.split(" ");
    if ("Who".equals(arr[0])) {
        res.append(Ans(arr[2]));
    }
    if ("Where".equals(arr[0])) {
        res.append(Place(arr[2]));
    }
    Output.TF_value.setText(this.TF_1.getText());
    Output.RES.setText(res.toString());
    n1.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: You should read about java coding styleguies. You variable names are violating them all over the place. That confuses any experienced programmer reading your code, without any need too. Besides names like n1, inp, arr ... say nothing about the object they denote. Try to come up with names that really help one to understand what is going on.

Comment: [Problem with multi-line JTextField](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6662029)

Comment: Sir I have noted your suggestions and I will work on them. However, to make my code simpler to read, I shall explain briefly the meaning of variables used:

inp: A string variable to take user input

arr: An array of string which is used to convert inp into array

res: A string where the result gets stored

RES: Textfiled where the result gets displayed

n1: Object of class Output.java